# Exception (MAIN_THREAD) using Firebase InstanceID and RxJava 2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Our application is getting the `FirebaseInstanceId` with the following code :

```
Observable.create<ReactiveStreamResult> {
    it.onNext(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
       .getToken(SENDER_ID, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE)
    )
}
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

But for some device this code triggered an `IOException` (MAIN_THREAD). Is it possible that the creation of the observable is done on the `MAIN_THREAD` not on the `IO Thread` ?

Can the defer operator solve this issue ?

Thank you for your answer
Best Regards

Guillaume

Comment: This code should not have caused that `IOException`. Are you sure the exception refers to it? Please provide the exception stacktrace and code demonstrating how you consume this observable (i.e., the `subscribe { }` call).

Answer (score 0):

The below example should not cause the issue, because you stream it correctly.

```
Observable.create<ReactiveStreamResult> {
    it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    it.onNext(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(SENDER_ID, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE))
    it.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    it.subscribe { // Do what you need to do here for the main thread }
}
```

However, since I only see this bit of the code, I urge you to also read the below documentations to understand it correctly.

[RxJava Schedulers](https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-schedulers-what-when-and-how-to-use-it-6cfc27293add)

[Understanding RxJava subscribeOn and observeOn](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea)

Comment: This is completely wrong. Those methods do not exist and wouldn't make sense either to apply them one by one to an observable.